# How to update a widget that pulls document data from Firestore when the stream gets updated based on user input?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm trying to build scrollable cards that updated the current number based on the card the user scrolls in place. So far I don't know how to do this other than wrapping the card in a gesture detector and increasing the buildingNumber

But what I'd like to know is how to update the information widget I made below it, to display the information corresponding to the buildingNumber. The buildingNumber is the document name in Firebase that holds the information that needs to be updated in the information widget.

so if the user scrolls, the buildingNumber goes from 1 - to - 2.
then the widget below the scrollable cards, should display the Firestore data corresponding with document(buildingNumber) but while I'm able to display the number when the app is built, I'm not able to update it even though it seems to be working behind the scenes.

Here is the code for the card & information widget:

```
Widget _buildingInfoCardState(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BuildingNumber())],
    child: Consumer<BuildingNumber>(
      builder: (context, buildingNumber, _) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('managit_buildings')
            .document(user.uid)
            .collection('buildings')
            .document(BuildingNumber.buildingNr.toString())
            .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loading();
            }
            var userBuildingInfo = snapshot.data;

            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 500,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 30, right: 30),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: codGrey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //  BUILDING INFO_NAME 
                      Text(
                        userBuildingInfo['buildingName'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70, 
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ...
```

The Gesturedetector that updates buildingNumber:

```
Widget buildingCard(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot building, index) {
  final buildingImage = AssetImage('assets/images/building1.png');

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTapCancel: () {
        BuildingNumber().increment();
        print(BuildingNumber.buildingNr);
      },
```

The BuildingNumber class:

```
class BuildingNumber with ChangeNotifier {
  static int buildingNr = 1;

  void increment() {
    buildingNr++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

As this is my first app, I am aware that what I'm currently doing is probably not the best way to go about things, so as I'm learning while doing I'm open for recommendations!

The problem: I'm able to display the information for building 1 but when I increment buildingNumber it doesn't update & show information in the building info for building number 2.

Comment: Is [Lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) what you are trying to achieve? If so, why are you using streams when you just fetch the data normally?

Comment: In my scaffold there are 2 main areas.

The top part (building cards):
this one is a scrollable ListView.Builder that shows you a preview of a building.

The bottom part (building Info Card) should update when you select a card from the top part. So when you scroll and select a building card, the building info card should update with the information stored in Firebase. 

Both cards pull their information from the same Firestore document.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your app to help visualise what you are trying to achieve? I am having some difficulty understanding your description.

Comment: Here you go! https://imgur.com/a/unpOQ4D

Comment: like @JoãoSoares asked if its lazy loading you can check the following article

Comment: @Ggriffo I don't think so.